# iis rewrite virtual subfolder path

Tags: iis, path, url-rewriting, virtual, subdirectory

1. I try change the subfolder path (virtual directory) via rewrite module on IIS
2. I want change the url path from "www.site.com/photos/20/be2f-8ed24a0d1a9a.jpg" to "www.site.com/photos/20_new/be2f-8ed24a0d1a9a.jpg" where "/photos" is virtual directory and "/20" its subfolder
3. I write rule:

```
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <clear/>
        <rule name="photo path rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="/photos/20/(.*)" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="{HTTP_HOST}/photos/20_new/{C:1}" redirectType="Temporary" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
      <rewriteMaps></rewriteMaps>
    </rewrite>
```

4. What I doing wrong? Thanks:)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules You use the wrong patterns, and use FRT to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Could you explain the URL you want to redirect belong to src attribute or you just want to access the URL directly?

If URL is accessed directly, you just need to change your condition input from {QUERY_STRING} to {REQUEST_URI}.

If this url belong to "src" attribute in the html img tag , then you can try this  outbound rule.

```
<rewrite>
        <outboundRules>
            <rule name="outbound rule" preCondition="IsImage">
                <match filterByTags="Img" pattern="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/photos/20/(.*)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" value="{HTTP_HOST}/photos/20_new/{C:1}" />
            </rule>
            <preConditions>
                <preCondition name="IsImage">
                    <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                </preCondition>
            </preConditions>
        </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
```